# how call noVNC console from rest-api oVirt

Tags: rest, ovirt, novnc

I am a junior programmer, and I am coding a small web-front-end for oVirt using REST-API. My front-end can create, change, start, stop, and delete vm. But have a problem, I don't understand how to call the noVnc web console. I can get a ticket, proxy ticket, file .vv to connect from virt-viewer.
This link open console from admin portal `https://ovirt.local/ovirt-engine/services/novnc-main.jsp?host=ovirt.local&port=6100&title=50add455-ffbc-4bfb-bf0b-2dd41d083d83%20-%20noVNC`  but not work if insert another vm title

Please help, how call noVNC console?